# Groundcover that will thrive in (Zone 9A) in Sierra Pine forest environment?

Tags: plant-recommendations, ground-cover

I am looking for practical suggestions for an aggressive groundcover that will  discourage Manzanita and will not require more than one or two annual trimmings to keep less than 12 - 16 inches in height?

Comment: Does "Sierra" mean the Sierra Nevada mountains in California?

Comment: What is the shade situation?  How much light does this area receive?  Manzanita is one of the most beautiful indigenous shrubs I know.  Almost impossible to culture and transplant.  The fact you have this manzanita (pictures will help ID this stuff) is a very enviable PROBLEM.  But we want to help.  You will want to focus on indigenous plant material such as bitterbrush, buffalo grass.  You COULD plant gag, Periwinkle, that might work for what you want but I can tell you pulling that stuff out of many gardens has made me hate the stuff.  Need to know how much shade you've got.

Comment: Hi, Stormy! Thanks for the reply.  The property in question is located in  Pollock Pines, CA near Placerville, CA about 60 miles east of Sacramento.  About 1.7 of 3.2 acres is mostly cleared.  It receives a lot of morning sun as well as a fair amount of afternoon sun.  The elevation is about 3800 ft.  The lot is mostly oriented W<>E, with a broad moderate slope from East to West and a lesser mostly gentle NorthEast to Southwest.  The existing flora is most weeds, mountain misery, sugar pines, some fir, a few cedars, and recently Manzanita.  I need ground cover that is low maintenance. IDEAS?

Comment: Sorry, ...YES, "Sierra does mean "Sierra Nevada" This property has a magnificient view of the Crystal Range or the Sierras in front of Lake Tahoe.

Answer (score 2):

I am reluctant to say Asiatic jasmine; it grows too well in the Houston area. It gets about 16" deep, but, it will climb anything to many feet. It is all over my yard and heading into the National Forest (mostly Loblolly pine).